Inter-Branch Transactions feature error on warehouseid inserting a Purchase Order through API Endpoint when Json is correct
Hi I am trying to create a purchase order and I cant get past this inter-branch transaction error.
I have the feature turned off and dont want to turn it on.
When I make a call (see below json)
I have the correct branch on the header and the line and the correct warehouse (warehouse is under that branch) it still gives me this error.
"PurchaseOrder.Details[0].Warehouse: Inter-Branch Transactions feature is disabled.\nInserting  'PO Line' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.",
I can key the same PO through the UI no problems.  The inventory item does have a default warehouse of main which is on the other branch so its like after the send to the api its defaulting MAIN onto my warehouseid and overwriting my specified warehouseid of AUCKMAIN.  Any help would be appreciated
I make this call on the Default endpoint
{
"Branch": {
        "value": "RBYTEAUCK"
    },
"VendorID": { "value": "ARKTAK" },
"Details": [
    {
        "BranchID": { "value": "RBYTEAUCK" },
        "InventoryID": { "value": "CABLFITTNG" },
        "OrderQty": { "value": 1 },
        "WarehouseID": { "value": "AUCKMAIN" }
    }
]
}

}
I have found by adding the line
"Hold": { "value": false },

the call then works with the PO being open and my values there but this line does not work on my custom endpoint and Hold field is not a field anymore in latest versions.  It should work without it.
